# Python Huey throws huey.exceptions.HueyException: xxxxxx not found in TaskRegistry

Tags: python, django, python-huey

I'm trying to integrate Huey with Django where I'm almost done with the initial setting of app and everything with **redis**. Now when I'm running the actual **.py** file I'm getting an exception **huey.exceptions.HueyException: xxxxxxx not found in TaskRegistry**. I have followed all the steps mentioned in [here](https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django.html) but still no luck so far. Can someone please help and throw some light on what I'm missing or if something is wrong. Thanks in advance.

Below is my code and app settings:

> schedule_task.py

[image: Task schedule code]

> settings.py

[image]

> Command which I'm using to run the schedule_task.py

```
python manage.py shell < hueyTasks/schedule_task.py
```

> Redis running on my local
> [image]

> python manage.py run_huey command to run the consumer
> [image]

Comment: This is beside the point but in general it's better to include code as text rather than screenshots. For formatting help: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @Radu Sure I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Your consumer isn't finding your tasks. Assuming that you've added `'huey.contrib.djhuey'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` [as described in the docs](https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django.html#setting-things-up), the likely issue is that you've named your task containing file something other than `tasks.py`, which is what Huey's Django integration relies on for auto-discovery:

> To run the consumer, use the run_huey management command. This command will automatically import any modules in your INSTALLED_APPS named tasks.py. The consumer can be configured using both the django settings module and/or by specifying options from the command-line.

Alternatively, you can eschew the auto-discovery feature, but then you have to restructure your code a little bit. See [docs](https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/imports.html#suggested-organization-of-code) for details. My recommendation is that you just rename your file `tasks.py`.

Comment: I have the same problem and everything is configured as you said.

Comment: @Rom1, might be best to post a separate question with your code

Comment: No it's okay, it did not work because I did not import task from huey.contrib.djhuey, but from RedisHuey('my-app').task